# pouchdb.find is not a function

Tags: reactjs, webpack, pouchdb, create-react-app

I have an react app created using create-react-app. So using webpack which is bundled with create-react-app.
I have to use find() of Pouchdb, which I am unable to do. Other Pouch functionality is working fine but `find` plugin is not getting attached to Pouch.

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-find'));
```

Versions in package.json :

```
"pouchdb": "^6.4.1",
"pouchdb-browser": "^6.4.1",
"pouchdb-find": "^6.4.1"
```

Do anyone have Idea how to fix this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the way to solve this problem. Hope it will help others

```js
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
import PouchdbFind from 'pouchdb-find';

export class PouchService {
    constructor() {
        PouchDB.plugin(PouchdbFind);
    }
}
```

After this find() gets included in PouchDB objects.

Answer (score 3):

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb-browser';
import PouchDBFind from 'pouchdb-find';
PouchDB.plugin(PouchDBFind);



let db = new PouchDB('employees');
db.find({
            
  selector: {age: 18}
}).then(doc => {
  console.log(doc) //queries the documents
});
```

Make sure you do `npm i pouchdb-browser pouchdb-find --save` first.

Answer (score 2):

Complementing the answer of Yash Kochar

```
import PouchDB from "pouchdb";
import PouchdbFind from 'pouchdb-find';

export default class Model{
    constructor(){
        PouchDB.plugin(PouchdbFind);
        this.db = new PouchDB('todos');
   }

   search(){
     this.db.find({
        selector: {name: 'MARIO'},
     }).then(function (result) {
     }).catch(function (err) {
       console.log(err);
     });
   }
}
```

NOTE: don't forget of install: "npm install pouchdb" and "npm install pouchdb-find" before

Answer (score 1):

Since we are doing PouchDB initialization and configuration, I've put the code in its own `db.ts` file:

```
const PouchDB = require('pouchdb');

PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-find'));

export const db = new PouchDB('my-db');
```

Also, I am using node `require` syntax.

It works very well and is ready to be reused.

References:

1. https://pouchdb.com/guides/setup-pouchdb.html#typescript
2. https://pouchdb.com/guides/mango-queries.html