# Why is PouchDB.find() not a function?

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I can't get the [pouchdb-find](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb-find) plugin to work. The closest I can get is a 'find is not a function' exception.

- Platform: Windows Firefox and Android Chrome 75.03770.101
- webpack: ^4.30.0
- pouchdb: ^7.1.1,
- pouchdb-find: ^7.1.1

I tried the approach from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186831/pouchdb-find-is-not-a-function), but it doesn't help

I also tried to use pouchdb-find with pouchdb-browser.

Below is the problematic code that I have currently. The PouchDB module itself won't work without adding the .default at the end of the require. Note that I *did* already populate a database with data prior to attempting to use .find().

```
// npm install --save pouchdb
// npm install --save pouchdb-find

const PouchDB = require('pouchdb').default;
PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-find'));

const db = new PouchDB(dbName);    
db.find({
    limit: 100
});
```

I'm open to any solution that allows me to use the pouchdb-find plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to mimic the way I was requiring PouchDB. (Also, the object passed to find() creates an error because it's supposed to have a selector, but that's not really relevant to the question's topic)

```
PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-find').default);
```