# createIndex is not a function

Tags: pouchdb

I am working on a WebDev project which uses Vue, Typescript and PouchDB/CouchDB.

Considering the following snippet, db.createIndex or db.find cannot be found:

```
import * as PouchDBFind from 'pouchdb-find';
PouchDB.plugin(PouchDBFind);
PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-find'));

let db = new PouchDB('employees');
db.createIndex({
  index: {
    fields: ['_id'],
  },
});
```

I have already read and tried out the suggestions in other posts like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48186831/pouchdb-find-is-not-a-function), but I still cannot get it to work.

I have made sure that `pouchdb-browser`(`pouchdb` module is not used in the project) and `pouch-db-find` are installed.

Comment: `import PouchDB from "pouchdb"; import find from "pouchdb-find"; PouchDB.plugin(find);` should be all you need. Mixing require and import doesn't seem right at all.

Comment: Thanks this worked. If you repost this as an answer, I will accept it as solution.

Comment: Happy to have helped. I am good leaving things as they are, thanks though!